# How to Create QR Code using some input data in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, qr-code, barcode-scanner

Is there any One having sample app or Idea about generating QR CODE generating using some input data by user,like ID,Name,Address,etc.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can opt here for generating QR code

these are third party library 
1) https://github.com/myang-git/QR-Code-Encoder-for-Objective-C
2) https://github.com/kuapay/iOS-QR-Code-Generator

but if you really want to know the concept this is a good start 
http://www.onbarcode.com/products/iphone_barcode/barcodes/qrcode.html